# How to resolve issue - Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.2 Gb in R

Tags: r, clustering

I'm using daisy function with a data set consists of 14 columns and 57,557 entries. Data set contains both categorical and numeric values .
It is failing with the error - Error: cannot allocate vector of size 6.2 Gb . Below is the code :
gower_dist <- daisy(trainData,
                    metric = "gower",
                    type = list(logratio = c(5,9,10,13)))

I've 16 gb memory and i've tried running after closing all other applications . Before running daisy function memory available was shown as around 13 gb and after running it's showing the available memory as 540 mb and it's failing.

Comment: This questions should be moved to StackOverflow.

Comment: Use a **different algorithm**. Anything that does not require a distance matrix, because you don't have enough memory. Pro tip: experiment with a sample first. *First* find an approach that *works*, then solve the scalability. You don't need to worry about solving an out of memory for an algorithm that doesn't work on a sample.

Answer (score 2):

Package [bigmemory](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bigmemory/index.html) and other "big"-named packages can be used to manage large amounts of data without storing all them in memory at once.